# AS3 concatenate items over different frames

Tags: actionscript-3, concatenation

I have two different frames. In frame 1, I have data for 5 different combo box responses (cbox1 to cbox5). In frame 2, I have data for an additional 5 combo box responses (cboxM1 to cboxM5).

In frame 2, I have  a function in which the data from all combo box responses are concatenated to one String variable (titled dataComplete in my example below), with each response being separated by an asterisk.

```
var dataComplete:String = cbox1Data + '*' + cbox2Data + '*' + cbox3Data + '*' + cbox4Data + '*' + cbox5Data + '*' cboxM1Data + '*' cboxM2Data + '*' cboxM3Data + '*' cboxM4Data + '*' cboxM5Data;
```

The problem I run into when I trace dataComplete is that ONLY the data from the CURRENT frame, i.e., cboxM1-cboxM5 seem to be included in this new dataComplete String. The data from the previous frame cbox1 to cbox 5) reads "null" in the output.

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: May I ask why you are doing this with two frames and not just in a single frame? Have you tried having your actions on two layers. Frame one actions in one layer with a keyframe on frame one and extend this layer into frame two by adding another frame to the timeline. Then on another layer add a keyframe in frame two and you other actionscript in there? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hello Andrew. The reason why I'm using multiple keyframes is because I'm constructing a survey. Each part of the survey is on a different keyframe. Would you still recommend a multi-layer approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each keyframe has its own scope independant of other frames. You cannot see from one keyframe thye code in another keyframe but what you can do is have one keyframe in it's own layer that covers the entire timeline (no other keyframe in that layer timeline). Now any code in that special keyframe can see all code in any layer/keyframe (if the playhead is there). Also all code in any other key frame can see the code in that special keyframe. For example you could have in that special keyframe a variable in which you store the result of all your combobox. That variable will always be visible by other code.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is use one frame. That way all your logic lives in one frame, Then have your survey questions inside a movieclip. You can then use the different frames of the movieclip to show different questions. Another approach would be to have each survey question in it's only movieclip, then hide and show movieclips based the current question. Would that work for you?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I'm sure your approach would work as well, though I went with the path of least resistance. Sorry that I don't have enough reputation points to mark your response as useful.